# How to evaluate this line integral?

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, vector-spaces

I am asked to evaluate the line integral $\int_C x^2dx + xy^2dy + dz$, where $C: [0,1] ->R^3$ is given by $c(t) = (x(t),y(t),z(t)) = (t^2,t,1)$

I started to approach this question by saying that  $\int_C x^2dx + xy^2dy + dz$ =  $\int_0^1 f(c(t))*||c'(t)|| dt$.

But I am unsure how to evaluate this when there is $dx, dy$ and $dz$ in the original integral.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT:**

We have for $x=t^2$, $y=t$, and $z=1$.  The differentials are $dx=2t\,dt$, $dy=dt$, and $dz=0$.

$$\int_C (x^2\,dx+xy^2\,dy+dz)=\int_0^1\left((t^2)^2(2t)+(t^2)(t)^2+0\right)\,dt$$

Can you proceed from here?

Comment: That makes sense! Would the answer then come to 1/2 + 1/5 + c ?

Comment: Not quite. I obtain $1/3+1/5$.  What is $c$?

Comment: Sorry I made a calculation error, yep I agree with the $1/3 + 1/5$. I just put c as the constant of integration (should I not bother including it)?

Comment: OK!  Well done.  And there is no integration constant as this is a definite integral, not an indefinite one.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

$$\int x^2dx+xy^2dy+dz = \int (x^2,xy^2,1)\cdot \vec {dx}$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $f: (x,y,z) \mapsto (x^{2}, xy^{2},1): C[0,1] \to \mathbb{R}^{3}$; then
$$
\int_{C[0,1]} f\cdot dC \equiv \int_{C} x^{2}dx + xy^{2}dy + dz \equiv \int_{t\in [0,1]} f\circ C(t)\cdot C'(t) = \int_{t \in [0,1]} 2t^{5} + t^{4}.
$$